# Try to use Homogeous space Characterize the space of all lines in the plane .

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

The problem is just to gives a smooth manifold structure of all straight lines in $\mathbb{R^2}$ ( not just those which pass through the oringin).Moreover, identify it with a well-known manifold!

*My sketch of proof:* Regard the straight line as a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Step1: I try to introduce a transtive Lie group action. Set $G=\mathbb{R^2}\rtimes S^1$ $((v,z)\cdot (v',z')=(v+zv',zz'))$ and it can act on $M$ by$(v,z)\cdot l =v +zl$ (here $l\in M$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$).

Step2: Consider the isotropy group of $G_m$ of the x-axis $m\in M$. One can easily prove that
$$G_m=\{(v,z):v\in m,z=1 or -1\} \approx \mathbb{R} \times S^0$$
is closed in $G$

Step3: Now use Homogeneous Space Characterization (one can see GTM218, Introduction to Smooth Manifold,2nd edited, Page552, theorem 21.18 and Page554 theorem21.20),and then we can get
$$M \approx G/G_m$$
where$G/G_m$ is the coset space.

However, I cannot continue. I cannot give a simple representation of $G/G_m$.I cannot identify $M$ with a well-known manifold.

Finally, I state the theorem I have used:(one can see GTM218, Introduction to Smooth Manifold,2nd edited)

**Theorem21.20** Suppose$ X$ be a set and we are given a transitive action of a Lie group $G$ on $X$ such that for some point $p\in X$, the isotropy group $G_p$ is closed in G. Then $X$ has a unique smooth manifold structure with respect to which the given action is smooth.

Comment: Theorem 21.18 doesn't apply here, because part of its hypothesis is that $M$ is a homogeneous $G$-space. This is defined on page 550, and requires that $M$ already have a smooth manifold structure.

Comment: @Jack Lee: Sorry for a little mistake. We can apply theorem 21.20 instead, which just require M to be a set.

Comment: It looks like Theorem 21.20 gives your result directly; you don't need to know anything about $G / G_m$.  What do you feel is missing from that argument?

Comment: Presumably you prefer to find a smooth structure which is compatible with some other information such as the symmetries of the plane.  Otherwise, you could simply observe that the set of straight lines can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the real numbers, and then use the smooth manifold structure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wham I am interested in is how to identify $M$ with a well-known manifold, not the abstract representation $G/G_m$